# Какой тип должен быть возвращаемым для getInstance()?

Tags: php

```
class Singleton {

    private static $instances = [];

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instances[static::class])) {
            self::$instances[static::class] = new static;
        }
        return self::$instances[static::class];
    }

    protected function __construct() { }

    protected function __clone() { }

    protected function __wakeup() { }

}
```

Какой возвращаемый тип должен быть для `getInstance`

```
public static function getInstance() : self
// или
public static function getInstance() : static::class // и можно ли так делать?
```

Этот класс предполагается использовать для наследования другими классами, в которых нужен один объект (например logger).

Можно ли для этого сделать этот класс абстрактным, т.к. самостоятельно этот класс не имеет смысла ? Правильно понимаю, что для этого нужно просто добавить`abstract` и ничего в классе менять не нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Не получится у тебя указать тип возвращаемого значения, тут generics нужны, а в php их пока что нет :)

```java
Logger logger = Singleton.getInstance<Logger>();

abstract class Singleton<T>{
  public static T getInstance(){
    // ...
  }
}
```

Вот так было бы в java к примеру. В PHP придется не указывать тип возвращаемого значения, либо реализовать какой нибудь костыль по типу

```php
protected static function _getInstance(string $class)
{
   if(!isset(self::$instances[static::class])) {
            self::$instances[static::class] = new static;
        }
        return self::$instances[static::class];
}
```

и в дочерних реализовывать метод

```php
public static function getInstance(): self
{
   return parent::_getInstance();
}
```